# Avoid overlap with community cookbooks

Tags: chef-infra

What is the common way to avoid overlap with community cookbooks?

Since I am learning Chef, I do not always use all community cookbooks. Instead I write my own versions.

However now I am in a situation where I need lots of functionality from the community version.

I thought I could survive prefixing my cookbooks with "foo-" but that is giving me problems (and hideous names) for my custom lwrp.

Should I just stick to use a common prefix for all my custom cookbooks "foo_" or is there a better alternative to prevent overlap?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The general pattern for wrapper cookbooks (which is what you're describing) is `<company>-<cookbook>`. For example, if I worked for Acme and had a custom apache cookbook, I would name it `acme-apache2`.